# Drop table using mybatis xml-mapper

Tags: oracle, mybatis

I'm trying to drop a table in my mybatis mapper but.

```
<update id="dropTable" parameterType="String">
    DROP TABLE #{name}
</update>
```

This generates a query like:

> drop table 'TEMP_TABLE';

Oracle does not like this syntax. I'm looking for a way to add the #{name} argument without the "'" chars.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Yes. That's what I want to do. The name argument does not have any quotation marks in it. Mybatis adds them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `${name}` instead of `#{name}`.

Under "String substitution" paragraph of [documentation](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) you can find details if you want.

Remember to **sanitize your data**, as string substitution **puts a raw string right into query**.